# What's the story behind the new SG-1 patches introduced in Ex Deus Machina?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In *Stargate SG-1*, season 9, episode 7 (*Ex Deus Machina*), Lt. Col. Mitchell makes
quite a show of replacing the patches on the uniforms of SG1.

[image: new patch on Daniel Jackson's arm]

[image: Mitchell showing new patch to Carter]

What's the big deal? And, what did they replace?

The [Stargate Wiki post on this episode](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ex_Deus_Machina) doesn't mention it, based on a glance-over.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the Stargate Wikia [(on the SG-1 team)](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/SG-1):

> On Earth, during a mission to expose Ba'al, Mitchell formally re-formed SG-1 with Carter, Jackson, and Teal'c. (SG1: "Ex Deus Machina")

and ["Ex Deus Machina"](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ex_Deus_Machina_(episode)):

> Lt. Colonel Cameron Mitchell unites Lt. Colonel Samantha Carter, Dr. Daniel Jackson and Teal'c under his command at last

The SG-1 team had split up. Mitchell was given command of the team but needed to find new members. "The big deal" was that he had been trying to reunite the old team, and finally succeeded. The patches didn't replace anything but an empty space, as they were not formal members of any team until then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he removed something before pasting on the new patches.

Comment: I'd need to rewatch it. Maybe it was a SGC badge or something? I'm confident in the rest of my answer though.

Comment: No, I remember it well as I watched them all recently. They weren't a part of any team. Mitchell worked really hard to get them together, when everyone said it wouldn't happen, so he was proud that he'd managed it.

Comment: It was possibly a generic SGC badge, but he replaced it with the familiar SG-1 badge as a show of reuniting the team. Good answer. :D

Comment: That's right: he took off the generic base personnel "SGC" patch, and replaced it with a SG1 patch, after confirming with a smile and a nod that Teal'c and Carter finally accepted his offer to come back to SG1 and "get the band back together".

Answer (score 0):

The old patch showed the symbol of the Tauri. The new one is an SGC-themed logo, symbolising Mitchell getting the team back together.

Comment: Any chance you could post a picture of the previous version?